# How an Ansible playbook can create zip file on remote server , even though that remote server does not have zip binary?

Tags: ansible

Believe the title says it all - I am learning Ansible, and if I run a playbook that contains :

```yaml
- name: archive  is created
  archive:
    path:
    - /tmp/hello.txt
    - /tmp/hi.txt
    dest: /tmp/hh.zip
    format: zip
```

The zip file is created on remote/target server as per playbook, but... that remote server does **not** have the zip library:

```
ubuntu@markws:~$ zip --help
Command 'zip' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install zip
```

My question is then, how is it possible that this playbook creates the archive on the remote server, when there is no such utility installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the Ansible `community.general.archive` module [source code](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/files/archive.py) where you will find out that it is not using the command line `zip` utility but the [Python `zipfile` builtin module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

Comment: And you could probably generalise the observation to lots of other modules. Ansible generally (but there are, of course exceptions) uses Python modules and not shell commands.

Comment: @Marek, if you are interested in background information about modules and how they are developed, you may proceed further with learning in [Developing modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html).